# Flutter navigation buttons on BottomNavBarSection

Tags: flutter

I’m fairly new to flutter, I’m making a desktop app and I wanted to make a "setup-like" app, with Go Back and Next buttons. But I can’t find how to go to previous page a go to next page using a BottomNavBarSection and BottomNavigationBarItem.
What I have right now are the two items (go back, next) on the NavBar, and I have a switch that checks the index and depending on it, it does a `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage())` and the FirstPage changes depending on the page, but I can’t do an on tap specific to back or forward button.

Full BottomNavigationBar code:

```
class BottomNavBarSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: (index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
            );
            break;
          case 2:
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
            );
            break;
        }
      },
      selectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
          ),
          label: 'Go Back',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward,
          ),
          label: 'Next',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to know a better way to have "Go back" and "Next" navigation buttons, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Navigator.pop` to go back to a previous screen.